# Problema con <mat-expansion-panel> de Angular Material, e imprimir de Chrome

Tags: angular-material, mat-expansion

tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar en Angular Material v15.
Tengo un proyecto con varios mat-expansion-panel, igual al del del ejemplo típico de la página de Angular Material, dentro de un mat-accordion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso tengo 10 desplegables con mucho texto.

El problema es el siguiente:
Cuándo los despliego todos y le doy a imprimir "Ctrl + P" en Chrome (pasa lo mismo en Edge), y quiero hacer un pdf, me genera uno donde le faltan varias páginas del final. Alrededor de un 10% aproximadamente del total del texto.

Siempre ocurre cuando el texto está dentro de estos mat-expansion-panel y sólo sale bien cuando saco el texto de ellos.
Es como si el navegador no supiera entender el alto que ocupan las cabeceras de los desplegables y se lo resta al espacio final a imprimir.

¿Alguien sabría solucionarlo para que angular material no tuviera ese error?
Muchas gracias de antemano.